# passing references to the model between different table view controllers

Tags: ios

I am learning iOS. I have a table view controller that takes a booksdatacontext object (stores book objects) as its datasource. I want to show a report sorting these books by price as a second table view. How do I/should I reference the model (ie data controller object serving as datasource) in this second table view? Right now, I'm trying to assign the 2nd view's dataController in the first view's prepare for segue method--but getting the error below.

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"priceReport"]) {
    priceReportViewController  *priceController = [segue destinationViewController];
    priceController.dataController = self.dataController; //throws -[UINavigationController setDataController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 

}
```

I have declared a datacontroller property in the .h file of priceReportViewController

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "booksDataController.h"

@class Book;

@interface priceReportViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) booksDataController *dataController;
@end
```

Comment: Error says that there are no dataController declared in priceReportViewController class. So you might have to define one as an @property variable there in priceReportViewController.

Answer (score 0):

The destination of your segue is a UINavigationController. Access it's root view controller property to get you price list view controller and then set the dataController property of that

EDIT:
Alternatively, you could just (as you did) link your segues to the actual view controllers in your storyboard, not the navigation controllers in which they are embedded.

Comment: I changed my segues in the storyboard to point to the view controllers  embedded in the nav controllers--instead of the nav controllers. thanks for pointing me in right direction. if you put my solution in your answer i will accept.